# custom regex in route requirements

Tags: symfony, yaml

I'm trying to make a route parameter match an alphanumeric value that's 3 to 15 characters long. Code looks like this:

```
TestBundle_new:
pattern:  /message/new/{name}
defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Message:new }
requirements:
    name:  [a-zA-Z0-9]{2,15}
```

Unfortunately routing.yml fails to load. I was wondering if there is anything I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to add quotes around your pattern.

```
name: "[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,15}"
```